# Why "no match for 'operator<'" when I declared it?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, namespaces, operator-overloading

It works for the `struct xy` that I declared. Why doesn't the same pattern work for `complex<int>`?

```
#include <complex>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct xy {
    int x, y;
};

bool operator< (const xy &a, const xy &b) {
    return a.x < b.x;
}

bool operator< (const complex<int> &a, const complex<int> &b) {
    return a.real() < b.real();
}

int main() {
    xy q;
    set<xy> s;
    s.insert(q);

    complex<int> p;
    set< complex<int> > t;   //If I comment out these two lines,
    t.insert(p);             //it compiles fine.

    return 0;
}
```

The error message:

```
In file included from c:\m\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string:48:0,
                 from c:\m\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\m\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\m\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\m\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\istream:38,
                 from c:\m\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\sstream:38,
                 from c:\m\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\complex:45,
                 from test.cpp:1:
c:\m\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h: In instantiation of 'bool less<>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const':
c:\m\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_tree.h:1321:11:   required from 'pair<> _Rb_tree<>::_M_get_insert_unique_pos(const key_type&)'
c:\m\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_tree.h:1374:47:   required from 'pair<> _Rb_tree<>::_M_insert_unique(_Arg&&)'
c:\m\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_set.h:463:29:   required from 'pair<> __cxx1998::set<>::insert(const value_type&)'
c:\m\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\debug\set.h:220:59:   required from 'pair<> __debug::set<>::insert(const value_type&)'
test.cpp:28:19:   required from here
c:\m\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h:235:20: 
error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const std::complex<int>' and 'const std::complex<int>')
       { return __x < __y; }
```

My best guess is that this has something to do with `complex<T>` being a class, not a struct. By I can't see the logic of why that should make a difference. Or is it some template horribleness?

What I see happening is that the STL at some point tries (roughly speaking) to do `a < b`, where `a` and `b` are `complex<int>` instances. So it's looking for `bool operator< (const complex<int> &a, const complex<int> &b)`. Well, there is exactly that declared just above `main()`. Why is it being unreasonable? I thought maybe it didn't like them being references. But removing the ampersands made no difference to its complaint.

Comment: I believe it has to do with " point of definition" and " point of instantiation". I'm just unable to recall all the intricacies. Please have a look at them.

Comment: @Nawaz Do you mean the rule that we have to declare a function in the text of the program *before* we use it? (After the preprocessor preprocesses all the `#include`s.) That seems to make sense, but then I don't understand why the case of `struct xy` works... Perhaps the operators like `operator<` are always implicitly declared?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to write a custom comparison functor, and instantiate the set with this.

```
#include <complex>
#include <set>    

bool operator< (const std::complex<int> &a, const std::complex<int> &b) {
    return a.real() < b.real();
}

struct my_less {
    bool operator() (const std::complex<int>& lhs, const std::complex<int>& rhs) const{
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::complex<int> p;
    std::set< std::complex<int>, my_less > t;
    t.insert(p);

    return 0;
}
```

[Sample on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfab2b25f35ed877)

Comment: it's UB to add `operator<` for `std::complex` inside `namespace std`

Comment: @TemplateRex Ok, true, I'll reduce it to just the functor.

Comment: A more general rule I found is that adding anything at all to `namespace std` is Undefined Behaviour, with some limited exceptions. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25120423/1143274), which quotes the relevant paragraph from the standard.

Answer (score 3):

> It works for the `struct xy` that I declared. Why doesn't the same pattern work for `complex<int>`?

The reason is that when you use types from namespace std only, like `std::set` and `std::complex`, the compiler has no reason to look for operators in any other namespaces.

With `struct xy` this is different, as the operator is declared together with the type.

---

And also, the current standard says:

> The effect of instantiating the template complex for any type other than float, double, or long double is
>   unspecified.

So using `complex<int>` might, or might not, work depending on which compiler you use. "Unspecified" is not as bad as "undefined", but 
of course not very reliable or portable.

Comment: *"the compiler has no reason to look for operators in any other namespaces."*  This is wrong. The compiler can, does, look for names in other namespaces as well, especially in the global one. It all depends on the point-of-definition  (and possibly, point of instantiation).

Comment: As of today I face this issue, so I agree that it's an unspecified behaviour. Have noted 1 workaround in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63686831/514235). This might help for the non-std namespaces at least. @Nawaz

Comment: ah, yes. That is how ADL works. It works in the namespaces in which types are originally defined. But @iammilind, your comment *"so I agree that it's an unspecified behaviour"* is not correct, as we are referring to the lookup rules (which is pretty much well-defined). Unspecified is different thing here, not the actual problem though.

Comment: @Nawaz, may be you are right. But I feel it's unspecified because a global `operator==` works for a namespaced class and `operator<` doesn't!

Comment: That might be a bug? Also, such things are not likely to be left unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, I am facing this issue with my Ubuntu's g++. Suppose I have:

```
namespace X { namespace Y { class C { ... }; } }
```

Now `operator==` is recognized if it's defined in a global namespace, such as:

```
bool operator== (const X::Y::C& lhs, const X::Y::C& rhs) { return lhs == rhs; }
```

However, somehow compiler doesn't recognize `operator<`, if defined in the same way.

Now following way works well:

```
namespace X { namespace Y { 
     bool operator< (const C& lhs, const C& rhs) { return lhs < rhs; } } }
```

However, whether you should do it the same with expanding standard `namespace std` is a controversial topic. :-)